# Understanding strange behavior with ToExpression in DynamicModule: Losing Apply

Tags: dynamic

### Short Version

Consider the following code:

```
test = "I";
label = "I";
paramlist = {a, b};
ToExpression[StringReplace[test, {label -> "(v2@@paramlist)[t]"}]]

(* v2[a,b][t] *)
```

When I try this inside a DynamicModule, it fails:

```
DynamicModule[
  {dispVar2 = "I", 
   varyingparamlist, 
   fitExpression = "I", 
   fitfn}, 
  varyingparamlist = {a, b}; 
  fitfn = ToExpression[
            StringReplace[fitExpression, 
              {dispVar2 -> "(v2@@varyingparamlist)[t]"}]]; 
  Dynamic@Panel[fitfn]]

(* {a,b}[t] *)
```

What is going on here, and how can I get the correct expression inside a DynamicModule?

### Context

I have a system where I want non-Mathematica-savy users to be able to enter an expression in a (limited) natural notation for them as part of a dynamic interface. They can specify labels for variables and a system of differential equations which are then fit against experimental data using a combination of ParametricNDSolve and NonlinearModelFit. So if they specify

```
a S I
```

where S and I are the first and second time-dependent quantities in the system, this gets translated to

```
a v1[t] v2[t]
```

After solving the system of equations, I have parametric models that I need to access via something like:

```
((v1/.solution)@@varParams)[t]
```

The problem comes in when the fitting variable isn't a single value, like S or I. If I need S+I, I need to do something like:

```
ToExpression[StringReplace["S+I",
     {"S"->"(v1@@varParams)[t]",
      "I"->"(v2@@varParams)[t]"}]]/.solution
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.**

```
DynamicModule[{dispVar2 = "I", varyingparamlist, fitExpression = "I", 
  fitfn}, varyingparamlist = {a, b};
 fitfn = ToExpression[
   StringReplace[fitExpression, {dispVar2 -> "(v2@@varyingparamlist)[t]"}], 
   StandardForm, Dynamic];
 Panel[fitfn]]
```

[image]

**2.**

```
DynamicModule[{dispVar2 = "I", varyingparamlist, fitExpression = "I", 
  fitfn}, varyingparamlist = {a, b};
 fitfn = ToExpression[
   StringReplace[fitExpression, {dispVar2 -> "(v2@@varyingparamlist)[t]"}], 
   StandardForm, Hold];
 Dynamic @ ReleaseHold @ Panel[fitfn]]
```

[image]

**3.**

```
DynamicModule[{dispVar2 = "I", varyingparamlist = {a, b}, 
  fitExpression = "I", fitfn},
 fitfn = MakeExpression[
   StringReplace[fitExpression, {dispVar2 -> "(v2@@varyingparamlist)[t]"}]];
 Dynamic @ ReleaseHold @ Panel[fitfn]]
```

[image]

**Notes:**

```
DynamicModule[{dispVar2 = "I", varyingparamlist = {a, b}, 
  fitExpression = "I", fitfn},
 fitfn = ToExpression[
   StringReplace[fitExpression, {dispVar2 -> "(v2@@varyingparamlist)[t]"}]];
 Panel[fitfn]]
```

[image]

***What happened to `v2`?:***

- [Apply >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html): *"Applying to atomic objects that do not have subparts effectively does nothing":*

```
 foo @@ x
```

> ```
>  x
> ```

Now, wrapping this with `Dynamic` updates `varyingparamlist$$` and injects `{a, b}` for it:

```
DynamicModule[{dispVar2 = "I", varyingparamlist = {a, b}, 
  fitExpression = "I", fitfn},
 fitfn = ToExpression[
   StringReplace[fitExpression, {dispVar2 -> "(v2@@varyingparamlist)[t]"}]];
 Dynamic @ Panel[fitfn]]
```

[image]

That is,  `ToExpression` (without the third argument) evaluates the string `"(v2@@varyingparamlist)[t]"` before `varyingparamlist` is updated so that  `v2@@varyingparamlist` evaluates to `varyingparamlist$$` and the result is `varyingparamlist$$[t]`. Using the `Hold` as the third argument of `ToExpression` or  using [`MakeExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression.html) (which "returns the result wrapped in `HoldComplete`") prevents this untimely evaluation.

Comment: Works beautifully! Can you share some insights into *why* it works? Regardless, thank you!

Comment: @Kevin, added a few  comments re "why it works". Hope it helps.